# Liferay Using a package of ext-impl in another portlet

Tags: liferay

I have a serious problem that I can't resolve myself. I  created an custom portlet which uses three classes of portalImpl( LdapSettings, PrefsPortalUtils and PortalLdapImpl) but this package(ext-impl) isn't accessible by another portlet. How can I call ext-impl fonctions from custom portlet.
Thanks in advance,
Have a nice day

Comment: Use of classes from `portal-impl.jar` is discourage from `Liferay v6.0` and starting from `v6.1` you can't use it in custom portlet! So don't use it!

Answer (score 1):

You can't and you shouldn't. Why? all *impl classes are considered to be implementation detail and might change without notice. No assumption about interface or implementation stability can be made.

Now, are you stuck? No. For example you could rephrase your question and let us know what your problem is that you wanted to solve with access to those implementation classes and we might be able to point you to alternative solutions.

Of course, the fallback method is: If you definitely need the code you found there, copy it into your portlet. I won't tell you about the reflection-like cross-classloader access to the code, because that's not only discouraged, but also ugly and even worse in terms of maintainability.